# How to bind style attribute top and left in rivet.js

Tags: javascript, css, rivets.js

How do I *bind an object* such as i:

```
 var Item = function() {
        this.x = 10;
        this.y = 10;
    }
var i = new Item();
```

to a `div` that has style "`position: relative; left: {x}; top: {y}`"

Using http://rivetsjs.com/

Comment: Ok I see. Please let us know in the main post that you want to use http://rivetsjs.com/.

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a custom binder for that:

```
rivets.binders['style-*'] = function(el, value){
  el.style.setProperty(this.args[0], value);
};
```

... then ...

```
<p rv-style-left="item.x" rv-style-top="item.top">
```